# Is there a way in python to iterate over a log file through timestamps?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing my master thesis and trying to iterate over a log file in the way I am going to describe next:

My log file is a txt file in the following format:

```
Jul 27 16:51:30 Event 1
Jul 27 16:53:38 Event 2
Jul 27 16:55:38 Event 3
Jul 27 16:59:39 Event 4
Jul 27 17:05:39 Event 5
Jul 27 17:07:39 Event 6
Jul 27 17:12:30 Event 7
Jul 27 17:14:38 Event 8
Jul 27 17:15:38 Event 9
Jul 27 17:18:39 Event 10
Jul 27 17:21:39 Event 11
Jul 27 17:22:39 Event 12
```

I would like to read my log file with a time window of 15 minutes and time step of 5 minutes and append the results in a list. For example I have the empty list test_data = [] and would like to have this result:

```
print(test_data[0])
Event 1
Event 2
Event 3
Event 4
Event 5

print(test_data[1])
Event 4
Event 5
Event 6
Event 7
Event 8

print(test_data[2])
Event 5
Event 6
Event 7
Event 8
Event 9
```

Could someone help me with that? Is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.log') as f:
    test_data = []
    for i, e in enumerate(f):
        if i % 5 == 0:
            test_data.append('')
        test_data[-1] += e.split(maxsplit=3)[3]

print(test_data[0])
print(test_data[1])
print(test_data[2])
```

1. Open your log file using `with` and `as` a iterable `f`.
2. Init a empty list
3. Loop `f`
4. Each 5 steps which is requested by you in question, `append` a new blank string at the end of list.
5. extract `Event #` by split with `maxsplit=3` so that `Event` and `#` could group together.
6. `join` `Event #` to the end of list's last element. Then goto 4

Comment: My question was not to iterate every 5 steps. It has to do with minutes and time windows.